# How to set default CNAME subdomain for an URL

Tags: url, domains, dns

I created a free website in Google Sites and bought a new URL, www.example.com, from Go Daddy and configured CNAME subdomain `www` to my Google Site.

If I enter www.example.com in any browser it opens. But if I enter example.com (no www) it does not open my site.

I am sure that this problem is in the CNAME configuration. As per my knowledge CNAME subdomains are mail, www, ftp, etc.

How can I configure it so that if you enter the example.com URL it goes directly to the www subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a CNAME for your root domain (because a CNAME can't co-exist with any other record for the domain, and you have to have NS and SOA records for your root domain). There's no good solution to this if you don't operate your own infrastructure, except for ensuring that people always use www.myurl.com and not just myurl.com.

Comment: but all other global websites are able to open without www, is it because they have hosted in separate server? I am hosting freely in google sites and bought url from godaddy.

Comment: It's because they know the IP addresses of their servers won't change, and so they can set A records for them instead of CNAMEs.

Comment: The answer is absolutely correct. However, I'd like to mention that there are some DNS providers that offer proprietary solutions for this issue without the need to manage a custom infrastructure. *Disclaimer: I work at DNSimple and we were one of the first companies to offer such feature, known as the ALIAS record.*